# Scheduling a Powershell script to run weekly in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-lambda, active-directory

So, I've got the following powershell script to find inactive AD users and disable their accounts, creating a log file containing a list of what accounts have been disabled:

```
    Import-Module ActiveDirectory

    # Set the number of days since last logon
    $DaysInactive = 60
    $InactiveDate = (Get-Date).Adddays(-($DaysInactive))


    # Get AD Users that haven't logged on in xx days
    $Users = Get-ADUser -Filter { LastLogonDate -lt $InactiveDate -and Enabled -eq $true } -                
    Properties LastLogonDate | Select-Object @{ Name="Username"; Expression=. 
    {$_.SamAccountName} }, Name, LastLogonDate, DistinguishedName


    # Export results to CSV
    $Users | Export-Csv C:\Temp\InactiveUsers.csv -NoTypeInformation


    # Disable Inactive Users
     ForEach ($Item in $Users){
      $DistName = $Item.DistinguishedName
      Disable-ADAccount -Identity $DistName
      Get-ADUser -Filter { DistinguishedName -eq $DistName } | Select-Object @{ Name="Username"; Expression={$_.SamAccountName} }, Name, Enabled
    }
```

The script works and is doing everything it should. What I am trying to figure out is how to automate this in an AWS environment.

I'm guessing I need to use a Lambda function in AWS to trigger this script to run on a schedule but don't know where to start.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since you are using PowerShell, I presume you have an Amazon EC2 Windows instance running? If so, just use a Scheduled Task on that instance.

Comment: Could you clarify where are you running this script - in a cloud instance or locally on your machine?

Answer (score 0):

I recomment to create a Lambda function with dotnet environment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-powershell.html

Use a CloudWatch Event on a Scheduled basis to trigger the function:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html

An alternative, if you like to to have a more pipeline style execution you could use CodePipeline and CodeBuild to run the script. Use again CloudWatch to trigger the CodePipeline on a scheduled basis!